# Huh an empty folder that containers 42.8 GB?

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems

Empty folder with huge file size. Why is that?

[image: Empty folder with huge file size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Windows File Explorer, click on the View Tab, go to Options and make sure you are displaying Hidden Files.

[image: Hidden Files]

.

Also get a Trial License for Tree Size (Jam Software) and look at your drive with Tree Size.  That will find large (and hidden) files and should expose a very large file.  Local backup files are usually hidden and are large files.

I use Tree Size here and it is a good tool for this.